# JSDoc - How to document methods of a prototype object

Tags: javascript, documentation, jsdoc, jsdoc3

Based on my understanding of the naming inheritence in JSDoc, this should work defining `@name User.format#name` but it does not

```
/**
 * @class
 * @classdesc Stores the logged in user's information. Handles user updates and includes helper
 * methods for formatting users
 */
User = function() {};

/**
 * Object containing utility methods for formatting user objects
 *
 * @name User.format
 * @property {object}
 */
User.prototype.format = {
    /**
     * returns the full name of a user
     *
     * @name User.format#name
     * @param {User} user
     * @returns {string} the full name
     */
    name: function(user) {
        // some utility function
    }
};
```

Comment: You sure the # and . shouldn't be reversed?  'format' is an instance member of 'User', which means the # should be used.  'name' is an property of 'format', which means the . should be used.  So, User#format.name.